# Does an endomorphism of $K^n$ always admit a stable strict subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Does an endomorphism of $K^n$, with $n≥2$ and $K = \mathbb C$ or
>   $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$, always admit a stable strict subspace?

I know that if $K = \mathbb C$, all endormphism has an eigenvector (so it is true). And that if $K = \mathbb R$, for all endomorphism there exists a line or a plane stable (so it is true for $n≥3$, for $n=2$ we can consider a rotation in the plane). What about $\mathbb Q$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with integer entries and minimal polynomial
$x^n-2$, which is irreducible. This means that $\Bbb Q^n$ can have
no nontrivial proper subspaces invariant under $A$.